# Как импортировать классы из "родительского" каталога?

Tags: java, импорт, package

Господа, прошу помощи.
Что нужно прописать в import класса PopMusic (рис.2), чтобы из этого класса появился доступ к классам и интерфейсу в "родительском" каталоге (на уровень выше) ?

Спасибо.

[image: Структура]

[image: Класс PopMusic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, импорт класса из [безымянного пакета](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.2) невозможен.

Аналогичные обсуждения в английской версии:

- [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)
- [Import package with no name Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645950/import-package-with-no-name-java)

Answer (score 0):

Это теоретически возможно, но только через reflection API.

Поэтому, если у вас есть доступ к структуре, то лучше переместить файл(класс) из дефолтного в "именованный" пакет и импортировать его.